# Refreshing page keeps adding items to store

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm making a simple application with Sencha Touch, that shows a list with some data from a store.

Now, whenever I reload the application, the store keeps adding the same items. The first time there are 3 items, second time 6 items, next 9 items, and so on...

My ItemStore:

```
Ext.regStore('ItemStore', {
    model: 'ItemModel',

    proxy:
    {
        id: 'test-items',
        type: 'localstorage'
    },

    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.getStore('ItemStore').add({title: 'Test1'});
Ext.getStore('ItemStore').add({title: 'Test2'});
Ext.getStore('ItemStore').add({title: 'Test3'});
Ext.getStore('ItemStore').sync();
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using localstorage, which saves the data between page reloads. Try using memoryProxy instead.

From the documentation:

> MemoryProxy - holds data in memory
>   only, any data is lost when the page
>   is refreshed

Comment: Thank you! When I add an 'id'-field to the model, it also works. Strange?